# popup click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, openstreetmap, leaflet

How to make jquery event after click on the link in the popup (appears after click on the marker).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([54.6154, 18.8141], 7);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom:18}).addTo(map);
L.marker([54.6154,18.8141]).addTo(map).bindPopup("<a href='#' class='A1'>link</a>");
</script>
</div>
<a href='#' class='A1'>link</a>
<script>
$( '.A1' ).click(function() {
alert('halo');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That code is really hard to read, please improve your formatting (ideally putting a comment or something on the line that doesn't work). This question would get a quick "tab close" if I saw it while looking for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

The `.A1` link in the marker didn't exist when you created the handler.

You need to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to watch for events on `.A1` objects that show up later:

```
$(document).on('click', '.A1', 
  function() {
    alert('halo');
  }
);
```